# Office-js-helpers OAuth2 authentication using Okta?

Tags: office-js, okta, office-js-helpers

I'm trying to implement a custom endpoint for using in our Outlook add-in. I'm following this [article](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers).

Does anyone know how to implement this correctly? I have this code but it does not work (yet). What do I need to fill in inside 'clientId'?

```
    authenticator.endpoints.add('Okta', {
        provider: "Okta",
        clientId: "",
        baseUrl: "https://<customdomain>.okta-emea.com/oauth2/v1/",
        authorizeUrl: "authorize"            
    });
```

Comment: To use Oauth authentication,app must be registered in the Application Registration Portal. After registering your app, you will get ClientId. Please refer this for more details- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started#registering-an-app

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to login the user in to an application that is behind Okta (with SAML 2.0). The add-in needs to access it. I was trying to setup the authentication flow for this using the Office-js-helpers.

Comment: Please refer Okta documentation to get ClientId. This may help- [https://devforum.okta.com/t/where-is-the-client-id-information/4211](https://devforum.okta.com/t/where-is-the-client-id-information/4211)